# Ask for permission when clicked on download button

Tags: android, android-webview, android-permissions, android-download-manager

I am making an app with webView in Android studio. It contains pictures only so I also have an integrated download button in my app. In android Marshmallow version you have to ask for permission and I have a permission code in onCreate like this:

```
int check = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (check == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        //Do something
    } else {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1024);
    }
```

but it pops up when the app starts and I want to pop it up when the user clicks on the download button.

my download button in html looks like this:

```
<a href="url">Download</a>
```

and the download code in app looks like this:

```
 @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.endsWith(".jpg")) {
                    Uri source = Uri.parse(url);
                    // Make a new request pointing to the .apk url
                    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(source);
                    // appears the same in Notification bar while downloading
                    request.setDescription("Description for the DownloadManager Bar");
                    request.setTitle("PunjabiDharti.jpg");
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                    }
                    // save the file in the "Downloads" folder of SDCARD
                    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "PunjabiDharti.jpg");
                    // get download service and enqueue file
                    DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                    manager.enqueue(request);
```

How to pop up the request permission when the user clicks on the download button ?

Comment: Because u asking for permission in onCreate. You need to call ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission when button clicked. Assume that ur button is in WebView -> http://droidmentor.com/bind-javascript-to-android/.

Or call it in your shouldOverrideUrlLoading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it as follows:

```
public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final int DOWNLOAD_REQUEST_CODE= 1024;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.endsWith(".jpg")) {
                int check = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                if (check == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //DO the download stuff here
                } else {
                  requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},DOWNLOAD_REQUEST_CODE);
                }
            }
        }
     });
   }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if(requestCode == DOWNLOAD_REQUEST_CODE && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
           //DO the download stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> If you are using the `webview` then.., it can be achieved with `HTML5` too, instead of android code fore asking permission, then checking if permission granted or not, then saving to some location and .....

---

What you can do is.. Set `most of the properties` of `webview` like `javascript` and many more you can find on `developers documentation official google site`.

---

Now your `webview` is a`ble to do the most of the things that browsers can do` so :

---

Directly implement download of pictures on click / touch in HTML only AS :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click on the w3schools logo to download the image:<p>

<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>
<img border="0" src="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" alt="W3Schools" width="104" height="142">
</a>

<p><b>Note:</b> The download attribute is not supported in Edge version 12, IE, Safari 10 (and earlier), or Opera version 12 (and earlier).</p>
```

You can find it here [Click to see how it will work](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_download)

---

And do not forget to set the settings of the `webview` to make it able to work as most likely the browsers ; Settings [can be find here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings)